# Social login to community using instgram

Tags: community, single-sign-on

I have created Auth provider-

Auth. Provider ID 0SO0o000000TOPA 
Provider Type Open ID Connect 
Name - Insta 
URL Suffix - Insta 
Consumer Key - Instagram consumer key 
Consumer Secret - Instagram consumer secret
Authorize Endpoint URL- https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize 
Token Endpoint URL - https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token&scope=basic 
User Info Endpoint URL - https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self&scope=basic 
Token Issuer - 
Default Scopes- basic 
Send access token in header - Checked

Send client credentials in header - Not Checked

Custom Error URL
Custom Logout URL
Registration Handler - AutocreatedRegHandler1549709582209 
Execute Registration As - Amol Gaikwad 
Portal
Icon URL

I have created Register handler class-

global class InstagramRegHandler implements Auth.RegistrationHandler{

```
public static String ORG_SUFFIX = '@user.instagram.com';
private static final String DEFAULT_ACCOUNTNAME = 'Customers';
public static String EXTERNAL_USER_PROFILE = 'Customer Community User';



global User createUser(Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){

System.debug('Dumping Auth.UserData: ' + data);
System.debug('Registering Community user: ' + data.username);

   Auth.UserData d = normalizeUserData(data);

Id contactId;
contactId = createContact(d);
System.debug('Created contact: '+ contactId);            

   Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM profile WHERE name=:EXTERNAL_USER_PROFILE];
System.debug('Found profile: '+ p);

  User u = createUser(d,p);

u.contactId = contactId;
return u;
```

}

```
global void updateUser(Id userId, Id portalId, Auth.UserData data){
    System.debug('Update User called for: ' + data.email);

    User u = new User(id=userId);
    u.email = data.email;
    u.lastName = data.lastName;
    u.firstName = data.firstName;
    update(u);
}

private Auth.UserData normalizeUserData(Auth.UserData data){

    String fullname = data.fullName;
    List<String> names = fullname.split(' ', 2);
    if (names.size() >= 2){
        data.firstName = names[0];
        data.lastName = names[1]; 
    } else {
        data.LastName = fullname;
        data.FirstName = 'Unknown';
    }

   data.email = data.username + ORG_SUFFIX;

    return data;
}

private Id createContact(Auth.UserData data){
    Contact c = new Contact();

    c.email = data.email;
    c.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    c.LastName = data.LastName;

    c.Description = data.attributeMap.get('bio');

 List<Account> accounts = [select Id from Account where Name =:DEFAULT_ACCOUNTNAME];

    System.debug('Found account: ' + accounts);

    c.accountId = accounts[0].Id;            
    insert c;

    System.debug('Contact created for ' + data.email + ' id=' + c.id);

    return c.id; 
}


   private User createUser(Auth.UserData data, Profile p) {
    User u = new User();

    u.email = data.email;  
    u.username = u.email;
    u.FirstName = data.FirstName;
    u.LastName = data.LastName;

    String alias = data.username;
       if(alias.length() > 8) {
        alias = alias.substring(0, 8);
    }
    u.alias = alias;

    u.languagelocalekey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.localesidkey = UserInfo.getLocale();
    u.emailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    u.timeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
            u.profileId = p.Id;

    System.debug('User staged for ' + u.username);
    return u;
}
```

}

But I got the error is -

[image: N0_Oauth_Token:Access token was not returned]

Comment: Please use the `{}` button or Ctrl-K to format your code. I made this change for you but your latest edit overrode it.

Answer (score 0):

The registration handler Salesforce creates for you is just a template. You need to build it out and finish the implementation.

The most obvious culprit for the error

> List has no rows for assignment to sObject

which you raised in the original version of your question 
is

```
//TODO: Get an actual account
Account a = [SELECT Id FROM account WHERE name='Acme'];
```

The TODO is a guide to what you need to do to fix this.

I'm not sure how you get to that line in current state, though, because your `canCreateUser()` is hard-coded to return `false`, which blocks the SSO process from continuing. That's presumably the source of the other error you see.

Comment: I got the error No_Oauth_Token : Access token was not returned

Comment: Yes, you still need to complete the implementation of your registration handler all the way through.

Comment: I have changed my registration handler now I get the error is Missing_value:could not find unique third-party identifier

Comment: Hey @AmoGaikwad, we try to keep it to one problem per post; I can't really do iterative debugging in the comments. If you have a new problem, I'd suggest you try to debug it and if you're not successful open a new, specific question about this problem. It's nice if you can preserve the original question so that my answer actually makes sense to other readers.